# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object error

Tags: c#, oracle

I have written a simple console app in C# that i would like to connect to my oracle database but i'm running into some error and i hope someone can point me to what i may doing wrong.

I have the following:

```
void Connect()
{
    con = new OracleConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + "" +con.ServerVersion);
    Console.Read();    
}
```

app.config:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="connectionString" value="Data Source = (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = myservice)));User Id = user123; Password = user123;"/>
  </appSettings>
```

The error i'm getting is:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Comment: You might want to wrap that connection in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new `OracleConnection` object, doesn't automatically connect to the server. You need to manually connect first using [`connection.Open()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "...";

con.Open(); //<--- do this
```